# DataTable AJAX source

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I need to load a datatable from an AJAX source. My PHP script returns a JSON output in this form:

```
{
    "SiteID": "61",
    "SiteRef": "MI Swaco, Pocra Quay (Elect 910)",
    "SupplierID": "1",
    "StartDate": "2013-06-01 00:00:00.000",
    "EndDate": "2014-05-31 00:00:00.000",
    "Voltage": "LV"
},
{
    "SiteID": "8",
    "SiteRef": "UK Training Centre, (Elect 318)",
    "SupplierID": "1",
    "StartDate": "2013-07-01 00:00:00.000",
    "EndDate": "2014-06-30 00:00:00.000",
    "Voltage": "LV"
},
{
    "SiteID": "115",
    "SiteRef": "Smith Int, Bruce Fac (Gas 102)",
    "SupplierID": "31",
    "StartDate": "2013-08-01 00:00:00.000",
    "EndDate": "2014-07-30 00:00:00.000",
    "Voltage": "LV"
}
```

I have validated it via JSONLint and it says it is a valid JSON output. However when I use it for datatable it says invalid json output. This is how I am interfacing it with dataTable:

```
$(function() {  
    //$('#termTable').dataTable().makeEditable();
    $('#termTable').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "terminateContractList.php"
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": "SiteID"},
            {"data": "SiteRef"},
            {"data": "SupplierID"},
            {"data": "StartDate"},
            {"data": "EndDate"},
            {"data": "Volatage"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Please correct the spelling of Voltage in your code.

```
$(  function(){ 

            //$('#termTable').dataTable().makeEditable();
             $('#termTable').dataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "terminateContractList.php"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "SiteID" },
                    { "data": "SiteRef" },
                    { "data": "SupplierID" },
                    { "data": "StartDate" },
                    { "data": "EndDate" },
                    { "data": "Voltage" }


                ]
            } );


});
```

"Voltage" in the JSON data won't match the "Volatage" column in your dataTable

Comment: @Kunbi: please accept this answer. To do so, click the tick mark adjacent to it, so that it turns green. This is how we thank people on this site. Thanks!